# Irregularity of $\{a^x b^y c^z : x=2y \lor y>z\}$

Tags: regular-languages, pumping-lemma

> Show that $L=\{a^x b^y c^z : x=2y \lor y>z\}$ is not regular using the pumping lemma.

I know that in order to use the pumping lemma, I have to assume that $L$ is regular. Then I know that there is a $p$ such that every $w \in L$ such that $|w| \ge p$ can be represented as $xyz$ with $|y| \ne 0$ and $|xy| \le p$, so that $xy^iz \in L$ for all $i \geq 0$. But I have not been able to choose $w \in L$ that serves me to finish with the lemma, taking into account the restrictions that $L$ has.

Comment: Try to use a word which satisfies $x = y$ but not $y > z$.

Comment: I meant a word which satisfies $x=2y$ but not $y > z$.

Answer (score 1):

Simpler using Myhill-Nerode: Given a string $b^y$, $y ≥ 1$. Which is the longest string $c^z$ such that $b^y c^z$ is in L? The answer is different for every for every y, therefore a state machine must end in different states after processing $b^y$ for each y, therefore L cannot be recognised by a finite state machine.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose towards a contradiction that $L$ is regular, and let $n \ge 1$ be its pumping length.

Consider the word $a^{2n}b^nc \in L$. By the pumping lemma there is some value of $k \in \{1, \dots, n\}$ such that, for every $i \ge 0$, the word $a^{2n+(i-1)k} b^nc$ also belongs to $L$.

Picking $i=0$ yields the sought contradiction since $a^{2n-k} b^n c \not\in L$. We can then conclude that $L$ is not regular.

Answer (score 0):

It follows immediately from the pumping lemma that there is a k (the pumping length) and a $0 ≤ j ≤ k$ such that $a^k w$ in L implies $a^{k-j} w$, $a^{k+j} w$, $a^{k+2j}w$, $a^{k+3j}w$ etc. must all b in L.

That’s obviously not in L.